# Why empty collection assertion does not work in MSTest?

Tags: tdd, nunit, mstest

I have an assertion like the following

> Assert.AreEqual(1.Primes(), new List());

Where Primes returns IList and the code for primes is

> public static class PrimesKata
> {
> public static IList Primes(this int n)
> {
> return new List();
> }
> }

as you can guess I am trying out the prime number kata, when using MSTest for unit testing this test fails but the same code works just fine in NUnit. Is there something extra I need to do in MSTest for this test to pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit's `Assert` supports equality of collections.

MSUnit doesn't. You can use `CollectionAssert` in MSTest instead.

In .NET (unlike Java, for instance) two lists are *not* equal just because they have the same contents.